# How to get the best GPS position Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, android, html, gps, geolocation

I want to get the most accurate position of my mobile phone with android. I'm comparing accuracy value in 2 seconds interval and if value is less than last value I'm trying to keep the position in

. It looks fine but if accuracy of gps is less than 10 or 11 it doesn't save. I know that accuracy of phone gps is not big but it looks like a javascript bug. Any help? Here is my basic concept.

[check on your mobile phone browser](http://geomonitor.pl/test)

and code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button id="measure">measure1</button>

<button id="start">start</button>

<button id="stop">stop</button>

<p id="demo">x</p>
<p id="demo2">y</p>

<input type="text" id="demo3">reference accuracy <br>
<input type="text" id="demo4">last accuracy <br>
<P id="demo5"></p> 
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var y = document.getElementById("demo2");
var z = document.getElementById("demo3");
var q = document.getElementById("demo4");
var q2 = document.getElementById("demo5");


        document.getElementById("measure").onclick = getLocation;

        document.getElementById("start").onclick = clockStart;  
        document.getElementById("stop").onclick = clockStop;    

        var timerId // current timer if started

        function clockStart() {  
          if (timerId) return
          getLocation()
          timerId = setInterval(getCorrection, 2000)

        }

        function clockStop() {
          clearInterval(timerId)
          timerId = null
        }


  function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            } 
        }


   function getCorrection() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition2, showError, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            } 
        }       

        function showPosition(position) {   


                x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude +
                    "<br>Accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy +
                    "<br>Speed: " + position.coords.speed + " m/s" +
                    "<br>Altitude: " + position.coords.altitude +
                    "<br>altitudeAccuracy: " + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy +
                    "<br>Headin: " + position.coords.heading +
                    "<br>Timestamp: " + position.timestamp  ;

                z.value = position.coords.accuracy;


        }

          function showPosition2(position) {   


                y.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
                    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude +
                    "<br>Accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy +
                    "<br>Speed: " + position.coords.speed + " m/s" +
                    "<br>Altitude: " + position.coords.altitude +
                    "<br>altitudeAccuracy: " + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy +
                    "<br>Headin: " + position.coords.heading +
                    "<br>Timestamp: " + position.timestamp  ;
           //     window.document.body.onload = showPosition;  
                q.value = position.coords.accuracy;



            if ( z.value > q.value){z.value = position.coords.accuracy; 
                                    q2.innerHTML = position.coords.accuracy + " " +  position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude + " the best accurancy with positon";
                                    console.log('better')}


            else (z.value < q.value); { console.log('worse')}
        }


        function showError(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    x.innerHTML = "Uşytkownik nie zezwolił na geolokalizację?"
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    x.innerHTML = "Informacja o lokalizacji jest niedostępna"
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    x.innerHTML = "Przekroczono czas zapytania"
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    x.innerHTML = "Wystąpił nieznany błąd"

            }
        }



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to compare values with parseFloat() or parseInt() functions, like: if( parseFloat(z.value) > parseFloat(q.value) ). This way you will be sure that js will be comparing numbers and not strings. I am saying this because on a string comparation, "2" is bigger than "10".

Comment: It works. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Hi, i'm in the same problem, is it better than a watch? How it works to you? I'm performing a for looking for the best accuracy in 10 calls, but sometimes return really bad information, like accuracy 100 with sky clear

Comment: I guess it depends on browser which you are using. As I think the best accuracy is on firefox.